# Serilog not recording logs into MS SQL server, from .Net 6 Console App

Tags: logging, console-application, .net-6.0, serilog

I have added Serilog into one of my console applications but it is not recording logs in SQL server, nor it is throwing any error.
Please refer the code below:

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        MSSqlServerSinkOptions options = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions()
        { TableName = "SystemLog", SchemaName = "dbo", AutoCreateSqlTable = false };
    
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(appSetting.ConnectionStrings.LogDBConnString, options)
                .CreateLogger();
    
      services.AddLogging(loggerBuilder => 
                {
                    loggerBuilder.ClearProviders();
                    loggerBuilder.AddSerilog(logger);
                });
 services.AddTransient<Executor, Executor>();
 IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
   var executor = provider.GetService<Executor>();
    executor.Execute();
}



    public class Executor
    {
       private readonly ILogger<Executor> logger;
       public Executor(ILogger<Executor> logger)
       {
           this.logger = logger;
       }
        public void Execute()
            {
                logger.LogInformation("executor started");
                // Other processes goes here
            }
    }
```

Please point out, where and what I am missing here.

Comment: it is logging to console ?. i see that autotablecreation is false so did you made sure that you have created the tables before running your app ?

Comment: Yes the table is already created

Comment: And I am using logging into msmsqlserver

Comment: I tried your code. it seems your main application exits before it could write to sqlserver. just for test I added `Console.Readline()`  after `executor.Execute();` so that it waits before exit. and it added a entry in the table. so you need to give enough time to write to log before exiting from main.

Comment: I tried and added Thread.Sleep but now the logging is intermittent. sometime it is logging whereas most of the time it skips